# Playing audio stream using html5

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, rtsp, wowza

How can i play RTSP streams with HTML5 audio tag, I already check streaming links from wowza http and RTSP both work perfectly on VLC but when I embed these links in html5 audio tag, nothing seems to work any help would be appreciated. Here is my HTML5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="http://[ServerIP]:1935/bw/_definst_/mp3:audio/64kbps/A_B_C_D_Any_Body_Can_Dance_Bezubaan.mp3/playlist.m3u8" type="audio/mpeg">
            Audio not supported 
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit: Stream works on smartphones perfectly, but doesn't work on PC browsers**

Comment: you should probably look at MPEG-DASH.

Comment: Server side control is not in my hand, i'm given streaming URLs that work on VLC but not in wem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HLS (m3u8 files) will play on iOS (and some Android but support can be clunky) and Mac OS Safari in an HTML5 audio tag:
`<video width="640" height="360" preload="auto" controls src="http://[ServerIP]:1935/vod/test.mp4/playlist.m3u8"></video>`

RTSP can be played on Android via an a tag in Chrome:

```
<div id="myElement">
<a href="rtsp://[ServerIP]:1935/vod/mp4:test.mp4">watch this stream over RTSP</a>
</div>
```

RTSP should work in a HTML5 video tag on Android but only on the native browser (well that is my experience of it I normally use the a tag as Chrome is now the default browser in Android 4+): `<video width="640" height="360" preload="auto" controls src="rtsp://[ServerIP]:1935/vod/sample.mp4">
</video>`

To support desktop PC, either provide a download link to the video tag src (mp3, ogg, wav ..) or if you have to use a streaming protocol you will need to resort to a plugin like Flash (and feed it a RTMP or HDS feed).

There is the VLC plugin for web browsers that can allow playback of RTSP streams but that is in an embed tag:
`<embed TYPE="application/x-vlc-plugin" autoplay="no" loop="no" width="640" height="360" target="rtsp://[ServerIP]:1935/vod/sample.mp4"></embed>`

Though HTML5 video is protocol agnostic it is dependent on the web browser/OS manufacturer implementation and that can vary along time and manufacturers.

Comment: I need a solution which is cross, platform, and about mobiles it is working on most smartphones, and about a tag i am not sure if its a good idea because that takes user to mobile's native browser, so in that case I have no control over when the stream ends so I can bind corresponding events to it to create some sort of web music player.

Comment: For desktop there is a HLS to flash plugin here: https://github.com/denivip/osmf-hls-plugin. That means you are ok to use flash for your project for desktop support ...

Comment: Yes i am OK with flash player but flash player is last option for me :P

Answer (score -1):

```
<audio controls autoplay="autoplay"><source src="http://ip:port/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

worked for me on ie10, ff-chrome(win7) and android, iphone/ipad, im waiting to test on older ies-windows, safari and opera. Will not work on ie 8.